# What request to call a <input type="checkbox">

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

What request would a `<input type="checkbox" name="chkbx" checked >` return?

Normally I would do something like this:

```
if(Request["chkbx"] == true)
{
}
```

But that doesn't work with checkboxes.

Comment: You're doing it wrong. A strongly typed view with a `bool` property on your model will return `true` or `false`. That is how MVC should be used..

Comment: @SimonWhitehead: I know that I'm doing it wrong. But how do I do it right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In direct response to your question, the key returns `true,false` as a string in that case. So this is what you want:

```
if ((Request["chkbx"] as string).Contains("true")) {
}
```

It is just "false" if not checked.

Ideally though, you would create a model..

```
class Model {
    public bool IsChecked { get; set; }
}
```

..make your view strongly typed:

```
@model Your.Namespace.Model
```

Then use the `...For` helpers to bind your model:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.IsChecked)
    <input type="submit" />
}
```

Then in your action method.. you do this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult YourMethod(Model model) {
    if (model.IsChecked) {
        // your code here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding the 'id' property in your HTML and using that instead of the 'name' property